# Is there a smart way to reset the color of an object?

Tags: typescript, three.js

I am writing a program in typescript and I have `n` objects with default color red e.g. `cupe.material.color` is red.

Now I want to change the color of the cube by e.g. pushing `ArrowUP`. I have no problem so far.
The goal is when I change the color of an object x then it should reset if I set the color of another object. Only one object should have a non default color.

My idea was to create a variable which saves the initial color, but this doesn't work, take a look:

```
var box1 = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry(),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff})
); 

var box2 = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.BoxGeometry(),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xffffff})
);
var back;
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
   if(event.key == "ArrowUp") {
      box1.material.color.set("red");
      back = box1
      
    }
    if(event.key == "s") {
      box2.material.color.set("red");
      back.material.color.set("0xffffff")
      back = box2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store arbitrary values for a material object in its [userData](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.userData) property. So try this:

```js
box1.material.userData.originalColor = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

// later when you want to perform the reset

box1.material.color.copy( box1.material.userData.originalColor );
```

Comment: Hey, but this just works if you know the changed object. If i have 20 objects then it would be a problem, or?  BTW thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: No, since each material object has its own `originalColor` value.

Comment: They all have the same default color. The problem i see here, that i would have to to it with all 20+ objects, with 100 objects it would be 100lines of code in every if statement

Answer (score 1):

You can put your objects in an array and then loop through it, restoring the colors and then highlight the object you need (use usual number keys 0-9 (not on numpad)):

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 20);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let highlight = 0xffffff;
let boxes = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  let g = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry();
  let m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
  let c = Math.random() * 0x7f7f7f + 0x7f7f7f;
  m.color.set(c);
  m.userData.color = c;
  let box = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
  box.position.x = (-4.5 + i) * 2;
  boxes.push(box);
  scene.add(box);
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  resetColors();
  boxes[event.keyCode - 48].material.color.set(highlight);
  
});

renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

function resetColors(){
  boxes.forEach(b => {b.material.color.set(b.material.userData.color)});
}
</script>
```